# Regex - backtracking with the regex that only have literals

Tags: regex

Based on this reference: [reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)

It's said that: " *If a token fails to match, the engine backtracks to a previous position in the regex and the subject string where it can try a different path through the regex*"

I can understand this when regex contain recursion like this: `.*t` this will match the input "**acdat**d"

But what if the regex contains only literal like this:

regex:  `cat`

input: `Iam captain`

How does backtracking work in this scenario? Could someone explain this in the way that the Regex engine works?

Comment: If there is only one path through the regex then it doesn't need to backtrack.  Look at https://www.debuggex.com/   It shows you a graphical path through the regex - you can see the loops and forks in the path with .* or |  And if you want to see something else look at https://www.debuggex.com/r/Op_mk3bocezUtggR

Answer (score 1):

In a relatively simple implementation, the only backtracking necessary in your example would be if the processor saw the "ca" and then backtracked to "a" after it found the "p" instead of "t". In robust and commonly used implementations, it's unlikely that it'd actually have to backtrack for that though.

It's much more common when using wildcards like your first example.

Comment: What would it do at `a`? What's there to "backtrack" to?

Answer (score 1):

"Backtracking" means the regex engine goes back to a previous choice it made and does "the other thing", whatever that was.

Previous choices are remembered on a stack. Operations that push onto the backtracking stack include branches (`|`) and quantifiers (e.g. `*`).

If the stack of choices is empty, the regex engine gives up and returns failure. In the case of `cat`, there are no choices to be made.

Matching proceeds as follows:

There is an outer loop around the regex engine. It invokes the regex engine for every position in the input string (from left to right) and stops whenever a match is found. This is why regexes always find the leftmost match.

---

Offset 0:

```
Iam captain
^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 0. This fails (`c` does not match `I` and there are no choices to revise (the backtracking stack is empty)), so the loop tries the next position.

---

Offset 1:

```
Iam captain
 ^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 1. This fails, so the loop tries the next position.

---

Offset 2:

```
Iam captain
  ^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 2. This fails, so the loop tries the next position.

---

Offset 3:

```
Iam captain
   ^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 3. This fails, so the loop tries the next position.

---

Offset 4:

```
Iam captain
    ^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 4. This almost succeeds (`ca` is there), but `t` does not match `p`. The regex engine reports failure, so the loop tries the next position.

...

---

Offset 10:

```
Iam captain
          ^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 10. This fails, so the loop tries the next position.

---

Offset 11:

```
Iam captain
           ^
```

The regex engine tries to match `cat` at offset 11. That is, it tries to match the empty string at the end of the input. (Properly speaking this process should probably be illustrated by showing the cursor (`^`) *between* characters, not on them.) This also fails.

Now the outer loop has run out of positions to try, so the whole thing fails.

---

I like to think of it as this "outer loop" construct, so there is no real backtracking involved (that only happens within the regex engine).

Another way to think of it is that there is an implied `.*?` at the start of the regex. This would push the loop into the regex engine and make it step through all the positions as part of its backtracking.

Comment: could you please tell me more about your definition about backtracking, any Regex official documents that mentioned them.In my case does it mean my regex "cat" doesn't have component that force the Regex engine to choice like "|" or "*" or "+" so no choices have been saved to the stack and then the engine didn't perform backtracking.

Comment: @shinobitiger310 What do you mean by "Regex official documents"?

Comment: i means the source documents where you get that definition about backtracking